# On a $p$-adic unit and the existence of its $n$-th root

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}_p$ be the field of $p$-adic numbers.
Let $\alpha$ be a $p$-adic unit, i.e. an invertible element of the multiplicative monoid $\mathbb{Z}_p$. 
Consider the set $S = \{n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \gt 0\mid x^n = \alpha$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p\}$.
Is $S$ an infinite set?

Comment: Certainly not unless $|\alpha|_p=p^{nk}$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @AlexBecker $\alpha$ is a $p$-adic unit, which means that $|\alpha|_p = 1$. Regards.

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry.

Comment: This is not my domain, but I am somewhat surprised that in the context of $\Bbb Q_p$, the term "unit" means neither (1) neutral element for multiplication, nor (2) invertible element (which would just be "nonzero" in $\Bbb Q_p$), but (3) element of absolute value$~1$. Long live ambiguity! By the way, if this is so, why not just talk about $p$-adic _integers_ (where meaning (3) coincides with (2))? Clearly the $n$-th roots asked for are (unit) $p$-adic integers too.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It is customary in algebraic number theory that a unit of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ means an invertible element of the multiplicative monoid of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p$. In a ring theory, a unit of a ring $R$ means an invertible element of the multiplicative monoid of $R$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)

Comment: @MakotoKato: I knew the usual meaning of unit in ring theory; this is (2) of my comment. However the multipliciative moniod of $\Bbb Q_p$ is $\Bbb Q_p\setminus\{0\}$, as in any field, and all its elements are invertible. It is the implicit switch from $\Bbb Q_p$ to $\Bbb Z_p$ that surprises me.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen It is also customary in algebraic number theory that a unit of an algebraic number field $K$ means an invertible element of the multiplicative monoid of the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen
QUOTE:A $p$-adic number is called unit if it is not a multiple of a negative power of $p$ and its ﬁrst digit is nonzero. p.5
A Tutorial on $p$-adic Arithmetic
http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/docs/r09.pdf

Comment: Of course, the term $p$-adic unit is abuse of terminology.
In a correct terminology, it is an invertible element of the multiplicative monoid of the ring of $p$-adic integers or a unit of the ring of $p$-adic integers. But I rarely heard anyone said so.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation

Answer (score 6):

By Hensel's lemma, if $p\nmid n$ and $x^n\equiv \alpha\mod{p}$ has a solution $x\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$, then $x^n=\alpha$ has a solution $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$. Now, $\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, so for any $n$ with $(n,p-1)=1$, $x^n\equiv\alpha\mod{p}$ has a solution $x\in\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\right)^\times$. It follows that $S$ contains all $n>0$ with $(n,p(p-1))=1$, so $S$ is infinite.

Comment: Nice! I was going to attempt an answer, but I misread the question and thought it was asking about the set $R$ consisting of all roots of $\alpha$. I think $R$ is finite iff $\alpha$ is a root of unity. I'm just not sure how to prove it without using the $p$-adic logarithm, a tool which I've glimpsed but not studied. Do you happen to know of a more elementary proof of this statement?