# Algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Algebraic elements in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are well studied and there was a question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17032/which-p-adic-numbers-are-also-algebraic) about information regarding this.

I want to know following information:

Let $K_p=\overline{\mathbb{Q}}\cap \mathbb{Q}_p$. So we have extensions

$$\mathbb{Q} \subset K_p \subset \mathbb{Q}_p.$$
The first one is algebraic extension (of $\mathbb{Q}$) and next one is transcendental extension (of $K_p$).

**Q.** What is known about degrees of these extensions: $[K_p:\mathbb{Q}]$ and $[\mathbb{Q}_p:K_p]$?

Comment: Since $K_p$ is countable, the latter degree is uncountably infinite. I believe the former is countably infinite.

Comment: Some of the answers to my (very) old question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16724/how-far-are-the-p-adic-numbers-from-being-algebraically-closed) might be also relevant.

Comment: Also, just by the fact that $K_p$ has no algebraic extensions in $\Bbb Q_p$, and by cardinality arguments ($K_p$ is countable and $\Bbb Q_p$ has the cardinality of $\Bbb R$), the second extension has infinite degree.

Comment: @Wojowu: Since $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ is countable, $[K_p:\Bbb Q]$ is at most countably infinite. On the other hand, e.g. for $n$ odd and not divisible by $p$, $\Bbb Q_p$ and hence $K_p$ contains an $n$-th root of $1+p^2$, and for infinitely many such $n$, this root has degree $n$ over $\Bbb Q$, which implies that $[K_p:\Bbb Q]$ cannot be finite. So your belief is correct.

Comment: @Torsten: This fact (On the other hand ...) is interesting; roots of unity in $Q_p$ are $p-1$-th roots only, but roots of other elements can be of arbitrary height (in some sense). May I get to know some reference for (proof of) this fact?

Comment: See my answer. I originally wrote $1+p^2$ because I wanted to argue with exp and log and include the case $p=2$, but I've noticed now that's all not needed and we even have $n$-th roots of $1+p$ (and of course many other integers) for an unbounded set of $n$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarise some comments into an answer:

**A. $[K_p:\Bbb Q]$ is countably infinite.**

Namely, since the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[x]$ is countable, so is $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ and so is $K_p$, so $[K_p:\Bbb Q]$ is *at most* countably infinite.

To see that it's not finite, notice the following: For $x \in \Bbb Z_p^\times$, $\Bbb Q_p$ contains an $n$-th root of $x$ for all $n$ which are coprime to $p(p-1)$. (E.g. [by Hensel's lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/449973/96384); it is maybe noteworthy that [this characterises the set $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ within $\Bbb Q_p$, which can be used to prove e.g. that all automorphisms of $\Bbb Q_p$ are continuous hence trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/450696/96384).)

Now let's for example look at the element $\alpha:=1+p \in \Bbb Z_p^\times \cap \Bbb Z$. Notice that $\alpha$ can be a perfect $\ell$-th power $k^\ell$ with $\ell$ prime and $k \in \Bbb Q$ (necessarily $k \in \Bbb N$), for at most finitely many primes $\ell_1, ..., \ell_r$, and [hence for all $n$ with $gcd(n, 2\ell_1 ... \ell_r) =1$ the polynomial $x^n - \alpha$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133598/96384). So, for all $n$ with $gcd(n, 2\ell_1 ... \ell_r p(p-1)) =1$, the subextension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{\alpha}) \vert \Bbb Q$ of $K_p\vert \Bbb Q$ has degree $n$, where $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ denotes the $n$-th root of $\alpha$ existing in $\Bbb Q_p$ according to the previous paragraph. Since such $n$ can be arbitrarily high, $[K_p:\Bbb Q]$ must indeed be (countable) infinite.

**B. $[\Bbb Q_p: K_p]$ is uncountable, more precisely, has the cardinality of $\Bbb Q_p$ which is $2^{\aleph_0}$.**

This is just a cardinality argument using again that $K_p$ is countable, and so would be any countable-dimensional extension of it.

Comment: What does mean by "algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb Q_p$" ? Isn't just the set $\bar{\mathbb Q} \cap \mathbb Q_p$ ?

Comment: @ANG: That's how it is written in the question, although I do not like that (there is no natural superset in which one can take that intersection). I would just define it as $\{x \in \mathbb Q_p: x \text{ is algebraic over } \mathbb Q\}$.

Comment: Isn't $\bar{\mathbb Q} \subset \mathbb  C_p \supset \mathbb Q_p$ ?

Comment: Depends. How is $\overline{\mathbb Q} \subset \mathbb C_p$? Unless one defines $\overline{\mathbb Q} :=\{x \in \mathbb C_p: x \text{ is algebraic over } \mathbb Q\}$, in which case the definition in my previous comment has less redundancy. Some people define $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ as the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb C$, which is not naturally identified with $\mathbb C_p$. Or abstractly via polynomials and some kind of axiom of choice.

Comment: Yes, I understand it depends on situation. I found something [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17032/which-p-adic-numbers-are-also-algebraic?_gl=1*1dggqun*_ga*NTM5NjM3MDY3LjE2NzEzMzEzODM.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4MTMzODY2Ny4xMDEuMS4xNjgxMzQwNDA4LjAuMC4w)