# automorphism of $\Bbb{Q_p}$closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, valuation-theory

How to show that there does not exist an automorphism of $\Bbb{Q_p}$ except identity. Please help. Is any automorphism of $\Bbb{Q_p}$ already continuous.?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449424/an-automorphism-of-the-field-of-p-adic-numbers