# Frobenius action on $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $F_p$ be the Frobenius automorphism of $\overline{\mathbb F_p}$.

Given an explicit element $x $ of $\overline{\mathbb Q_p}$, how do I compute $F_p(x)$?

Does it even make sense?

Comment: The field $\Bbb{Q}_p$ has [no non-trivial automorphisms](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/449424/11619), so the Frobenius automorphism in particular is the identity there.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The Frobenius is never an automorphism in characteristic 0, so that proof doesn't apply. The map still makes sense in many situations. The question only claims that it is an automorphism of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your comment. I wanted to consider the algebraic closures. I edited the question.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the algebraic closure has a Frobenius automorphism. On the other hand there is a Frobenius automorphism for any unramified finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$. If $K$ is a finite unramified extension of degree $f$, then it is gotten by adjoining a primitive root of unity $\zeta$ of order $q^f-1$. The automorphism determined by $\zeta\mapsto\zeta^p$ is then the Frobenius automorphism.

Comment: @Matt: There is something called Frobenius automorphism for many a field of characteristic zero, for example number fields and a $p$-adic fields. When defined it induces the usual characteristic $p$ Frobenius in a quotient field of the ring of integers. I guess your point was that one should not try to use the same simple formula that works in characteristic $p$. That is, of course, correct.

Comment: (cont'd) so Matt is right in that you should not confuse the Frobenius automorphism of $\Bbb{F}_p$ or its closure and automorphisms with the same name in the context of $p$-adics.

Comment: I think usually the Frobenius is only defined on the maximal unramified extension $\mathbb{Q}_p^\text{unr} = \mathbb{Q}_p\left(\bigcup_{(n,p)=1} \mu_n\right)$, i.e. adjoin all the $n$th roots of unity with $n$ prime to $p$.