# How algebraically restrictive is the structure of $\Bbb Q_p$?

Tags: field-theory, p-adic-number-theory

My question is a little difficult to explain, but I will try to state it. First, let me talk about the field $\Bbb R$ of real numbers. Let $K$ be the maximal real algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$, that is, the maximal subfield of $\Bbb R$ which is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$. We have that the group of all automorphisms of $K$ is very small (!) in the sense that we do not have a lot of options to choose it: for example, any automorphism $f$ of $K$ must satisfy $f(\sqrt{d})=\sqrt{d}$ for all square-free positive integer $d$ (because every square is non-negative in $\Bbb R$). Under this context, I may say that $\Bbb R$ is *algebraically restrictive*.

My question is the following: Given a prime number $p$, does the $p$-adic field $\Bbb Q_p$ have an algebraic restriction in the sense that we can't choose freely an automorphism of the maximal subfield of $\Bbb Q_p$ which is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$? If it happens, how "big" is this restriction of $\Bbb Q_p$?

Comment: Using squares we can show that neither $\Bbb{R}$ nor $\Bbb{Q}_p$ themselves have any non-trivial automorphisms. Not sure to what extent this restricts the automorphisms of maximal algebraic subfields. See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/449424/11619) for the basic arguments. May be the links given there lead to something that helps you?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thank you so much for your hint. Using the arguments of the thread, you have that there exists only one automorphism of $\overline{\Bbb Q}\cap\Bbb Q_p$ for all place $p$ (I stand $\Bbb Q_\infty=\Bbb R$).